# word and line count from file

Tags: php, mysql

i am having one table a which contails all doc files i want to count the words from that doc file while editing or after editing and saving...please anyone help me out

Comment: what have you done so far ?

Comment: what version of word are we talking about ? do you have a beginning of the code? if you are looking for someone to supply the full code I advise you to use http://www.rentacoder.com/.

Answer (score 6):

update: you said are on windows

```
<?php

  $file = "somefile.txt";
  $lines = count(file($file));
  echo "There are $lines lines in $file";
?>

<?php
  $text = "This is some text.";
  $count = count(explode(" ", $text));
  echo "$text contains $count words";
?>
```

On posix system you could have done this in another way

```
<?php
  $lines_command = 'cat FILE_NAME | wc -l';
  $words_command = 'cat FILE_NAME | wc -w';
  $lines = system($lines_command);
  $words = system($words_command);
?>
```

See More at

```
$ man wc

WC(1)                                       User Commands                                       WC(1)

NAME
       wc - print newline, word, and byte counts for each file

SYNOPSIS
       wc [OPTION]... [FILE]...
       wc [OPTION]... --files0-from=F

DESCRIPTION
       Print  newline, word, and byte counts for each FILE, and a total line if more than one FILE is
       specified.  With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.

       -c, --bytes
              print the byte counts

       -m, --chars
              print the character counts

       -l, --lines
              print the newline counts

       --files0-from=F
              read input from the files specified by NUL-terminated names in file F; If F is  -  then
              read names from standard input

       -L, --max-line-length
              print the length of the longest line

       -w, --words
              print the word counts

       --help display this help and exit

       --version
              output version information and exit
```

Comment: Man: `wc [OPTION]... [FILE]...`, so `cat` isn't needed, or is `wc -l filename` not available on all platforms?

Comment: Download and install the GunWin32 file utilities on any Windows system and the wc command will be available just like on Unix systems. Then the wc information provided in the message thread will work.